# How to extract values contain in an array of Ext.data.Model?

Tags: extjs

I am using ext js. I have combo box where I am selecting a value and using this value as parameter to get other values (two values). Now I want this to be added to a variable so I can use it in other places other than the combobox. How can I do this?

```
var txtEP = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    renderTo: "txtEP",
    fieldLabel: 'End Point',
    triggerAction: "all",
    forceSelection: true,
    mode:'local',
    autoScroll: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    autoShow: true,
    typeAhead:true,
    store: genres,
    valueField:'pincode',
    displayField:'pincode',
    emptyText:'Select a Start Point',
    selectOnFocus:true,
    listeners : {
        'select' : function(){
            var selVal = this.getValue();
            store.load({
                url:'./genres1.php', 
                params: {pincode: selVal},
                callback: function(records) {
                    endpt = records; // here is where it is assigned
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Now my "endpt" will now contain an array of Ext.data.Model objects so which are the methods to extract values you need from them. Please help me

Comment: It looks like you did it already. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Ext.data.Model has a get method. You pass it the name of the field you want to get values with. In your case, you mentioned somewhere that `/genres.php` returns two values, if the data is returned as one record with two different columns like this:

column header: | value1 | value2

row 1: | 'data1' | 'data2'

You could assign the two returned data values to variables in your callback function like this, say you named your variables firstValue and secondValue:

```
firstValue = endpt[0].get('value1');
secondValue = endpt[0].get('value2');
```

If instead, your `/genres.php` returns the data as two different rows with only one column header like this:

column header: value

row 1: 'data1'

row 2: 'data2'

You could assign the data to variables like this:

```
firstValue = endpt[0].get('value');
secondValue = endpt[1].get('value');
```